# KeyError: Dictionary and Input

Tags: python, dictionary, random, input, keyerror

I am getting a KeyError. The `else` block isn't working. It keeps giving a KeyError when the input is something out of the dictionary, however it should `print("problem")`

please let me know if you know a way to fix this. Thank you.

```
words = {"good night": ["nighty night", "good night", "sleep well"],
         "good morning": ["good morning", "wakey-wakey!", "rise and shine!"]}

text_punk = input("text something: ")

punk = random.choice(words[text_punk])


if text_punk in words:
    print(punk)
    talk(punk) #this is for pyttsx3
else:
    print("problem!")
```

Comment: `punk = random.choice(words[text_punk])` That line of code is before the if/else.

Comment: You are accessing it before the `if` condition, that is where it should be throwing the error

Comment: thanks a lot @JohnGordon and shriakhilc for your help, I am really appreciated... I was about to go crazy!

Answer (score 1):

In this code, the exception is raised before you've checked `if text_punk in words`:

```
punk = random.choice(words[text_punk])  # might raise

if text_punk in words:
    print(punk)
    talk(punk) #this is for pyttsx3
else:
    print("problem!")
```

You could fix it by checking `words` before assigning `punk`:

```
if text_punk in words:
    punk = random.choice(words[text_punk])  # shouldn't raise
    print(punk)
    talk(punk) #this is for pyttsx3
else:
    print("problem!")
```

or by using `try/except` instead of `if/else`:

```
try:
    punk = random.choice(words[text_punk])  # might raise
    print(punk)
    talk(punk) #this is for pyttsx3
except KeyError:
    print("problem!")
```

Comment: thank you @Samwise for your answer and help, I am really appreciated it really worked!